# Firebase-admin : Query data as user from firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

The end goal here is to validate from an external server that a user can query a given document according to the Firestore rules in place.

What I would like to achieve is along the lines of

```
const idToken = request.headers.idToken;
const userFirestore = admin.firestore(token=idToken);

userFirestore.doc('/some/doc').get().then((data) => {
  console.log('successful authentication');
}).catch((e) => {
  if (e instanceof FirebasePermissionError) { // Or whatever condition to validate that it is a permission error
      console.error('Unauthorized', e);
      response.error(401); // handle permission error
  }
});
```

But it doesn't seem to be possible.

The solutions I see, and I kind of dislike both are :

#### Instanciate a new firebase client sdk when I want to validate a user

```
const userFirebase = firebase.initializeApp({ apiKey: idToken ... });
const userFirestore = userFirebase.firestore();
```

But I feel like this is heavy and hackish... Or is it?

#### Reimplement my firestore rules in the server

```
const uid = (await auth.verifyIdToken()).uid
if (documentUserWants.acl.includes(uid)) {
  console.log('authenticated')
} else {
  throw PermissionError();
}
```

This feels a lot less hackish than instanciating a firestore client every time but obviously a pain to maintain sync between firestore rules and this code

##### What is the best approach? Is the first version doable in some way I missed in the docs?

Thanks!

Comment: You *can* use a client Node.js SDK in your external server. For admin tasks in a secure environment we use admin-SDK, but you don't *have* to.

Comment: That is precisely my first suggested alternative "Instanciate a new firebase client sdk" but it doesn't feel right.

Comment: Not instantiate a new instance in the same code - literally create a separate program/server to run the NON admin SDK for you.

Comment: It's even worse, running one separate process per client connection. And then I found out that I can't authenticate directly with a user's idToken in the client sdk so I'm falling back on checking the rules manually.